# convert or parse milliseconds to timeframe [Python 3]

Tags: python, time, flask

I am writing an API using Flask to gets the number of `seconds` from the URI, convert it to `milliseconds`, and add it to the current time.

All the code works but the `finaltime` is currently in milliseconds. I would like to have it as `HH:mm:ss.SSS`. What would be the easiest way of going about this? I found some search results but most of them were not applicable to my case.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask

currenttime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))


@app.route('/api/<seconds>')
def api_seconds(seconds):
    milliseconds = int(seconds) * 1000
    finaltime = int(currenttime + milliseconds)
    return 'Seconds: ' + seconds + '<br />' + 'Milliseconds: ' + str(milliseconds) + \
       '<br />' + 'Time: ' + str(currenttime) + '<br />' + 'Final Time: ' + str(finaltime)
```

I tried `finaltime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f', time.gmtime(finaltime_ms/1000))` but it returned `Final Time: 01:45:24.%f` without the milliseconds. From what I understand, milliseconds isn't supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://bugs.python.org/issue1982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was abled to achieve desired result using:

```
import datetime
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
finaltime = currenttime + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=milliseconds)
print finaltime.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
```